# SQL Query to Join tables between dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database which records pager messages which has two tables, one is a table with messages and the other is a table with recipients, where the link between the tables is pagermessages.pcapcode = capcodes.bcapcode (a numerical address each pager message is sent to).

This works semi-well, and I typically use an inner or left join to show the various pager messages and who the messages are for.

The issue I have, is that the system is dynamic, and the pagers can be re-programmed so that address 1, which might have been for recipient EXAMPLE1 may eventually be changed to be for EXAMPLE 2.

This leads to the issue, that I want to store the messages in a historical form, but I need a way to be able to specify between a date range. My thought was to have in the Capcodes table a date & time (bStartDateTime) and a finish date & time (bFinishDateTime) and then in my query be able to use this to work out how to join the pager messages.

This is where I am stuck though, I would normally do something like SELECT * from PagerMessages INNER JOIN Capcodes ON PagerMessages.pCapcode = Capcodes.bCapcode however what I want to now be able to do is to do the same thing, but where the pager message date (pDateTime) is between bStartDateTime and bFinishDateTime (which could be blank) to link, but if it is outside of that then to not link.

So take this example

Pager Message Table

```
ID|pDateTime       |pCapcode|pMessage
1 |2014-06-24 14:00|1       |This is a test message
2 |2014-06-24 15:00|1       |This is a test message
3 |2014-06-24 16:00|2       |This is a test message
```

Capcode Table

```
CapcodeID|pCapcode|Name     |bStartDateTime  |bFinishDateTime
1        |1       |Example 1|2014-06-24 14:00|2014-06-24 14:30
2        |1       |Example 2|2014-06-24 14:31|
3        |2       |Example 3|2014-06-24 14:31|
```

In the above examples, what I would like to be able to do is to join the tables so that I can get a table like the below:

```
ID|pDateTime       |pCapcode|Name     |pMessage
1 |2014-06-24 14:00|1       |Example 1|This is a test message
2 |2014-06-24 15:00|1       |Example 2|This is a test message
3 |2014-06-24 16:00|2       |Example 3|This is a test message
```

So you can see, basically because the capcode exists twice in the pCapcode table, it has taken the entry in which the date & time falls between, this way I can then have multiple entries of the same bCapcode in the capcode table, and then if they get changed just add the date it was changed in the Capcodes table, and add a new entry rather than having historical entries that are no longer accurate as I can't select them properly.

Sorry if it does not make too much sense, I can clarify if needed but I think i have covered most of what I am asking, which is really what kind of an SQL statement would allow me to do the above, as it is not a simple INNER / LEFT JOIN from what I can see.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can still join them. Just make sure only use the finish time if it exists.

```
select a.id, a.pdatetime, b.name, a.pmessage
from PageMessage a
join Capcode b on a.pcapcode = b.pcapcode and b.bstartdatetime <= a.pdatetime 
     and (b.bfinishdatetime is null or a.pdatetime <= b.bfinishdatetime);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select  ID,pdatetime,pcapcode,0 as 'Name',pmessage from Pager_Message 
union 
select  ID,0,pcapcode,name,0  from Capcode
```